# Robot framework code to copy a apk file from Jenkins to a specific folder

Tags: android, batch-file, jenkins-plugins, robotframework

I am using an Android application for automation where I have to copy the latest version of apk file from Jenkins job Artifact to a specific folder and start the test suite execution. Currently I am copying a file using "wget" command to copy the apk from Jenkins to a specified folder- but, this task I am doing using a Windows batch command file.

Now, next task is instead of using separate batch file, I have to copy this apk from Robot file itself.

How can I accomplish this task?

Comment: You could create your own Python Keyword which does this for you and you pass in the params within RF.

Comment: Check it out:  http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#keyword-arguments